# How to run instruments with new instances from the command line?

Tags: ios, instruments, ui-automation

I want to have the ability to run scripts on multiple devices with instruments at the same time.

I found that if I open new instances of instrument `(File -> New)`,

I could run many scripts on different devices at the same time, but I need to run this from the command line.

I have the command:

```
instruments -t mytemplate myapp.app
```

and I can add to this:

```
-i # The index of the instrument to apply.
```

how can I find the index of instrument?

or how do I tell the command line to run a script on a specific instance of instruments?